# Extend element beyond container, but keep children within container

Tags: html, css

I've recently had a problem, where I want to keep all my content within a parent container, but I want the navigation background to be 100% of the width of the page. The methods I've tried have worked in terms of getting the navigation to be 100% width of the page, but now the ul inside isn't affected by the container, which is what I originally wanted.

I got it to work by using another container div inside the navigation, but I feel like this is a very makeshift method.

Any suggestions on how to get the parent container to affect the ul inside the nav?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#view1">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view3">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view4">CURRENT PROJECT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view5">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view6">CONTACT ME</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}

.menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
}

.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 80px;
    float: right;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `.container-fluid` would be a great choice I think. Here's jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qp8qy7mq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo selector for creating background effect that looks like having `width` equal to the `width` of the page.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu:before {
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  position: absolute;
  right: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#view1">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view3">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view4">CURRENT PROJECT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view5">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view6">CONTACT ME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it matter how far left or right I go? As in could i just do left: -1; and right: -1; or do I have to use a specific amount? Also I can't use position relative on the menu tag because the menu is meant to stay on the top of the page.

Comment: @ParadAUX If you wants `background` of `.menu` to stretch 100% browser width then better use `-9999px` for `left` and `right` properties. Bcz if you use in pixels like `-50px` then on page zoom out you might see blank space on both extreme ends.